# How to graph equations with complex coefficients?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, newton-raphson

How can I graph a function having complex coefficients? I don't really know how to do it even for a linear function like $(2+i)x+(3-5i)$. It would be great if you could explain it in the case of a quadratic equation, too.

Comment: can you tell the function?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi I forgot what the function was, but let's say it is $(2+i)x+(3-5i)$. It can also be a quadratic function but I just want to keep it as easy as possible to understand.

Comment: is $z_1=x+iy$ ?, you may plot Re and Im separately or take the moduli

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Yes, any complex number with $y\neq0$. It doesn't have to be something like in the question. You could also give an example, it's been a while I forgot about this question.

Comment: The question now is not about "any complex number". This is because you explicitly state $y=F(f'(z_1),f(z_1),z_1)$ . Creating a graph with no interpretable variables wont be of any use. Please note, If you've forgotten critical details the question can be closed shortly.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Thank you, I've just edited the question. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://jutanium.github.io/ComplexNumberGrapher/) or [this](https://people.ucsc.edu/~wbolden/complex/#((z%5E2+1)%5E2%20+1)%5E2%20+1)?

Comment: The simplest way is graph the real and imaginary part of the expression separately. Most graphics software these days allow you to put multiple curves in a single graph, so plotting both parts in a single graph isn't that hard.. Another way is graph the function as a parametric 3d curve. If you have access to a software which allow you to modify the view interactively, this will help a lot in visualizing the curve.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Probably the second one it is -even though I have no idea how to interpret it.- Thank you, I think I should wait a little more before learning to interpret this kind of graphs.

Comment: @achillehui What should I deduce from two functions in a single graph? For example, from these equations of the function in the OP: https://prnt.sc/v1neg3

Comment: 1) Both the real parts are linear functions. 2) Since the real part (the red curve) intersect the $x$-axis at $x = -2$, the function is imaginary there. 3) Since the imaginary part (the blue curve) intersect the $x$-axis at $x = 5$, the function is real there 4) Since the two curves doesn't intersect at any points on the $x$-axis, the function is never $0$. For more general function, sometime it is useful to think of them as a 3d curve and see whether they winding around the $x$-axis.  That's all what I can come out from my head.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks a lot!